# Raspberry Pi and RFM69HCW (Adafruit) not working - SPI used (URGENT)

Tags: spi, radio

I am working on a project, and I was trying to get the Pi 4 working with an RFM69HCW module. I tried using spidev for this, and read the spidev documentation. I followed the steps but I keep getting this error for my scrip with spidev imported: [image]

I am working on a Pi 4 with Python 3 and an Adafruit RFM69HCW radio module. Can someone let me know where I am going wrong?

Thanks,
T

Comment: The Pi appears to be irrelevant to the question which makes it off topic.

Comment: @Thira: Please confirm if you are reading the same documents as mine: (1) RFM69HCW ISM Transceiver Module v1.1 Datasheet - HopeRF 
https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Wireless/General/RFM69HCW-V1.1.pdf

(2) Descriptions of RF Transceiver Module RFM69HCW - HopeRF
https://www.hoperf.com/modules/rf_transceiver/RFM69HCW.html

Comment: Please give us a schematic and/or a photo showing the wiring between Rpi4B and RFM69HCW. Ref: RFM69HCW block diagram: https://imgur.com/gallery/y8taUEr.

Comment: Are you using a bare chip or a real/fake AliExpress/TaoBao AdaFruit 433MHz 3071 module? Ref: 3071 RFM69HCW TRANSCEIVER RADIO BREAK - ¥77
https://item.taobao.com/item.htm?spm=a230r.1.14.16.6ffbeedfHS16i0&id=675771441806&ns=1&abbucket=10#detail

Comment: More to confirm: Are you using AdaFruit M0 Circuit Python or Rpi4B Thonny Python, Wire or SMT uFL Connector, RadioHead Packet Radio Library?